# SetFontSize is deprecated in JRDesignStyle

Tags: java, scala, jasper-reports

Following [this example](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/noxmldesign/index.html#noxmldesign), the compiler is complaining that `setFontSize` is deprecated (I'm using Scala). How to set the font size?

```
   val normalStyle = new JRDesignStyle
   boldStyle.setFontName("DejaVu Sans")
   boldStyle.setFontSize(12)  // <--- this is deprecated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [see](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/base/JRBaseStyle.html#setFontSize(int)), this method replaced with new one: [*JRDesignStyle.setFontSize(Float)*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/base/JRBaseStyle.html#setFontSize(java.lang.Float)).

In *Java* your code will be:

```
boldStyle.setFontSize(12.0f);
```